# Reapply css style to a part of a view after binding list of data

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

Iam binding a toolbar with list of items on my page from database after opening a popup on the same page and when the binding is complete the css applied to that toolbar disappears. Please guide me how to keep the css applied to it even after binding as I am not reloading the page just binding data and the css style disappears.

js part:

```
var toolBox = new namespace.ToolboxData();
toolBox.initializeToolbox("Layout");
designerController.ToolBoxModel(toolBox.ToolBoxModel);
$('#accordion').multiAccordion().multiAccordion("option", "active", [0]);
```

html part:

```
<div class="scrollBar" id="accordianScroll">
  <div id="accordion" data-bind="foreach:ToolBoxModel">
```

So here after binding is complete then the css called through class disappears.

Comment: Can you post your code snippet along with the CSS?

Comment: I have a css file and I am calling a class and the binding is in javascript page and there is a view from where Iam using it still I'll  try to post some part.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser debugger console?

Answer (score 1):

This is for canvas, ignore otherwise:

If you are making your srcollbar in a canvas element....
Try something with `.save()` and `.restore()`. You can save the original state of your toolbar element say ....

`var mytoolbar = document.getElementById('canvasToolBarId');
mytoolbar.save();`

some code involving toolbar....
then

`mytoolbar.restore();`

Checkout [refference](http://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/).

Comment: Iam actually binding the toolbar with knockout so is it somehow related to that?

Comment: I am not sure how knockout treats the state of an element, but it may have something to preserve states before and after binding.